# How do I evaluate the integral of this function?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

[image]

The substitution is u= 5x+11

This is what I have done but it says the answer is incorrect.

$$ \frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{u^3}  \ \rightarrow \  -\frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{(5x+11)^2} \ $$

Comment: You don't mean $=$ there, since you've integrated. Can you find the antiderivative of $u^{-3}$? (It's not just $-u^{-2}$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to divide by a factor of $2$ due to the power rule: $\int u^n = \frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$.